# Network manager always fails to autoconnect to wireless networks after boot. Manually connecting works fine

Tags: linux, wireless-networking, arch-linux, networkmanager

On both of my latpops running arch linux and KDE plasma Networkmanager fails to autoconnect to a saved wireless network after login with the message `No secret provided` which is quite annoying. Connecting manually after it fails or disconnecting while it attempts to autoconnect and then manually connecting works fine.

`dmesg | grep wlp3s0` yields the following on both machines:

```
[    2.932334] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlp3s0: link is not ready
[    2.946381] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlp3s0: link is not ready
[    3.214407] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlp3s0: link is not ready
[    3.274321] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlp3s0: link is not ready
[   12.008032] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlp3s0: link is not ready
[   42.004698] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlp3s0: link is not ready
[   42.012632] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlp3s0: link is not ready
[   49.783058] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlp3s0: link is not ready
```

Any idea how this can be solved?